# Subscribe and update wont work together . Either one works and the other returns error and vice versa.

Tags: angular, ionic3, angularfire2

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';

    import{ShoppingItem} from '../../model/shopping-item-new/shopping-item-new2';

     import { ShoppingListPage } from '../shopping-list/shopping-list';





    @Component({
      selector: 'page-edit-shopping-item',

      templateUrl: 'edit-shopping-item.html',
    }) 

    export class EditShoppingItemPage {


    shoppingItem =  {} as ShoppingItem ; 
    Ref : AngularFireObject <ShoppingItem>;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
       public navParams: NavParams,
       private database : AngularFireDatabase ,


       ) {
    //captutre the shopping item id as a nav param
    const shoppingItemID = this.navParams.get('shoppingItemID');
    console.log(shoppingItemID);

  this.Ref = this.database.object(`shopping-List/${shoppingItemID}`);

    //this.Ref.subscribe(shoppingItem => this.shoppingItem = shoppingItem);
       }
```

The Code works  with the subscribe code above commented out. But i cant subscribe to the data so when  i want to update the current values dont show but the key is valid so whatver i input gets updated both on the app and on firebase.if i uncomment i the subscribe code and i can subscribe susseefully, but then the update code below then doesnt work. Also the subscripe part of the code only works when i attach valuechanges to the end of "this.Ref = this.database.object(`shopping-List/${shoppingItemID}`);" above. please how do i get the update and subscribe to work together. i was using an old tutorial which uses firelistobservable instead of the new angularfireobject. Ill appreciate any help please. new to programming so nothing is too small for me to learn . thanks.

```
     editShoppingItem(shoppingItem:ShoppingItem){

     this.Ref.update({
       itemName : this.shoppingItem.itemName,
    itemNumber: Number(this.shoppingItem.itemNumber)
     });
     this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad EditShoppingItemPage');
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two different references and it seems to have solved the problem.One to subscribe and another to update. I dont know if this is the conventional way but it works also on a different but similar issue. if anyone has a different answer im stil open to hear.thanks. This is the code below

```
Ref : AngularFireObject <ShoppingItem>;
Ref2 : Observable <ShoppingItem>;
```

Then this

```
this.Ref2 = this.database.object(`shopping-List/${shoppingItemID}`).valueChanges();
this.Ref = this.database.object(`shopping-List/${shoppingItemID}`);

this.Ref2.subscribe(shoppingItem => this.shoppingItem = shoppingItem);
   }
 editShoppingItem(shoppingItem:ShoppingItem){

 this.Ref.update({
   itemName : this.shoppingItem.itemName,
itemNumber: Number(this.shoppingItem.itemNumber)
 });
```